# How should I refactor my code in order to avoid the Network on Main Thread exception on Android?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

In my MainActivity I have a class initialization like so:

```
Presentation presentation = new Presentation("link");
```

Presentation is a class which gets initialized using values from a .JSON file on a web server:

```
public Presentation(String URL) {
    // Do stuff
    doNetworking();
}
private doNetworking() {
    // Network access here
    // This throws the Network on Main Thread exception
}
```

In my MainActivity, I need all the values of Presentation to be there in the next step:

```
Presentation presentation = new Presentation();
// Do some stuff with it
```

Using the AsyncTask I am not sure how I should go about doing this, so far I have something like this:
    public Presentation(String URL) {
        // Do stuff
        new InitializePresentation().execute(URL);
    }

```
private class InitializePresentation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
    // Amongst other things
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        // Do the networking stuff here
    }
}
```

What I need is to refactor this code so that it is asynchroneous but behaves like a synchroneous call. Any help is greatly appreciated.

*edit*
How does one refactor a code to accomplish this?

```
Bitmap b = new Bitmap();
Load bitmap from network;
Use bitmap in imageview;
```

Can this be used in this fashion? Or do I have to use it like

```
Async, doInBackground() {
   Load bitmap from network
   Use bitmap in imageview
   Continue with application
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can show a progress dialog while doing the network stuff:

```
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private Context context;

public InitializePresentation (Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "", "loading", true);
}

/* 
 * @see android.os.AsyncTask#doInBackground(Params[])
 */
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    // Do the networking stuff here
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(final String result) {
    progressDialog.dismiss();
}
```

Comment: If I use this code in the MainActivity, can I use it as a step inside a function or do I need to write the rest of the code for the app inside onPostExecute?

I will edit the question to have an example of what I mean

Comment: if this code needs to be done after the network stuff is finished, then yes add it in the onPostExecute..as using the asynch task is like openning a new thread

Comment: Also, is this a good code practice? Writing the code in the onPostExecute? Or is it a workaround?

It seems I also can't access the debugging section inside this async call. Can you comment on that?

Comment: depends on what you are doing, theoretically it's used to update the ui..read http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html